# Intersection of a MultipolygonZ and a floating point raster

Tags: postgis, raster, 3d

I am trying to isolate the pixels in a floating point raster (loaded in PostGIS) that intersect my MultipolygonZ table (also loaded in PostGIS) and whose values are less than or equal to the z values of the MultipolygonZ table - essentially a 3d intersection.

I am running PostGIS 2.1.5. SELECT postgis_full_version() returns:

"POSTGIS="2.1.5 r13152" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3924" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER"

Here's what I have tried so far:

1) ST_Intersects(rast, geom) - this simply calculates a 2d intersection between the polygons and the raster - the z values of the MultipolygonZ are ignored.

```
SELECT (ST_DumpAsPolygons(rast)).*
FROM pgz_tab, dem
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom)
```

2) ST_3dIntersects(rast, geom) - invalid arguments - apparently this only works with points and linestrings - http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_3DIntersects.html

```
SELECT (ST_DumpAsPolygons(rast)).*
FROM pgz_tab, dem
WHERE ST_3dIntersects(rast, geom)
```

3) Converting the MultipolygonZ to a floating point raster and then subtracting the two rasters. I can't seem to get the arguments right with the ST_AsRaster function - http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_AsRaster.html even after reading [A guide to the rasterization of vector coverages in PostGIS](http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.ca/2014/05/a-guide-to-rasterization-of-vector.html).

Answer (score 1):

You thought this through well, and it might be that raster subtraction is your best bet. But, just to leave it registered, as of PostGIS 2.2 [ST_3dIntersects() does work with polygons and TINs](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_3DIntersects.html). Creating said polygon3d or TIN from a raster in PostGIS is another problem entirely, but once it's done, the function will work just fine.

Regarding your problem specifically: [there are many ways](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_AsRaster.html) to work with ST_AsRaster(). Different parameters you can call, etc. In your case, the easiest might be the second-to-last one on the list, in which you only need to set 4 parameters:

```
ST_AsRaster(geom, width, height, pixel_type)
```

where geom is your geometry object, width and height the raster's dimensions, and pizel_type the [PostGIS' Raster Data Type](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_BandPixelType.html). Beware, however, that this will create only an empty raster, in which every pixel is set to value 1. You have to then set the values.

For that, you can use the [ST_SetValues()](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SetValues.html) function. It takes in a raster object, the raster band (first band is 1), and a geomval[] type. [GeomVal](https://postgis.net/docs/geomval.html) is an aggregate function that holds a set of geometries, and a set of values of each geometry - you can think of it as a point cloud, though you can construct it with linestrings and polygons as well. You construct it with Potsgres' array_agg (you can check [an implementation of it here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135893/how-to-add-a-band-with-conditional-value-to-a-raster-with-postgis)). Something like:

```
SELECT ST_SetValues(ST_AsRaster('POLYGON((0 0, 5 0, 5 5, 0 5, 0 0))'::geometry, 5, 5, '8BUI'::text), 1, geomval)
FROM (SELECT array_agg((p.geom, p.val)::geomval) as geomval
      FROM public.poly3d as p
) values
```

Quite a workload, to be frank, but if you can't upgrade your system to PostGIS 2.2 or above, you may have to make do with this.